# Code execution html/script with display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have created an offline HTML page that displays iframes from a remote access page (control panel). This enables us to get a quick overview of everything that is happening in a certain location. My question is a conceptual one. This HTML page has two formats, one horizontal and one vertical (portrait). All the iframes are embedded into a table from 5x3 in horizontal and 3x5 in vertical mode. Based on the width of the screen (with media query) the correct mode is selected. The other mode is disabled with the command `display: none;`. Both the 5x3 and 3x5 tables are in the codes.

Is it correct that with the `display: none;` only one mode is loaded and thus only one stream per iframe is started? Or are both iframes (in both tables) loaded and only one displayed, and thus causing twice the bandwidth? We want to extend the number of modes and we have to make sure that the bandwidth is as low as possible.

I look forward for your responses. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but an easy way to check is to try it, and use the Network console of your web browser to see if one or both URLs are being accessed.

Comment: This is really a problem that should have been solved with CSS Grid and not HTML tables (then you could rearrange it with CSS instead of duplicating content).

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking, are you asking if the css, display is none, is the frame content loaded?  If yes, then yes of course it is.  If you are controlling the css display value then you can control the frame content too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. My question is indeed whether the frames are still loaded when the content is not shown (with `display: none;`). I will look into the CSS grid instead of the HTML table. However, are the iFrames than loaded/active even when parts of the CSS grid are not shown? (I will test the network use asap but we are running an experiment so I can't do that anytime).